# Receiving text alerts on Macbook but not iPhone

Tags: iphone, macbook-pro, messages, alert

I have an iPhone 7. I only recently synced it to the Messages app on my computer. At first, I received text alerts on both devices, but now, when I have the computer open (not the computer's Messages app, just the computer) and get a new text, I get an alert on my computer but my phone doesn't light up. If I check my phone's lock screen, I can see that I got a new text, I just can't get my phone to alert me. When I close the computer, however, I receive alerts just fine.

Has anyone else experienced this? Is it normal or is there something I can do to fix it? Do Not Disturb and message forwarding are disabled.

Answer (score 1):

This is normal.  Messages notices you were sent the alert on your Mac so it doesn't alert again for the same message on your iPhone.

You mentioned that when you do get Messages alerts on your iPhone when your computer is locked or has the lid closed.  Messages is designed to not 'over alert' you when it believes you've already seen the alert.

Comment: I am having this problem too and I would really like to correct it. "Designed not to over alert" is not quite true – it has a setting available to allow repetition of alerts up to 10 times!

Comment: @PatrickM "Designed not to over alert" means you don't get the same alert on multiple devices at the same time.  The alert will display on the device it thinks has your focus.